# Getting next value from key inside nested dict

Tags: python

My old code stored a device_name.id and its assigned sACN universe in this form:

```
prev = {
  "312398": 1,
  "232312": 2,
  "312353": 3
}
```

Now im storing it as a nested dict with the additional attribute
`device_name.model` as follows:

```
current = {
  "312341": {
   "model": "Some-Model",
   "universe": 1
  },
  "532342": {
    "model": "Some-other-model",
    "universe": 2
  }
}
```

My old code had a function

```
def get_free_universe():
        return next(
           i
           for i in range(1, 128)
           if i not in conf.values()
    )
```

Called like this:

```
device_count = sdk.get_device_count() #setup Corsair devices config
for device_index in range(device_count):
    device_name = sdk.get_device_info(device_index)
    device_type = device_name.type
    if device_name.id not in conf:
        if conf.keys == " ":
            print("config empty, universer = 1")
            universe = 1
        else: 
            universe = get_free_universe()
        conf.update({device_name.id: {"model": device_name.model, "universe": universe}}) 
        print(f"conf= {conf}")
    else:
        universe = conf[device_name.id]
```

Now of course the part `if i not in conf.values()` doesnt work anymore. I need to look at every dict for its key `universe`. How can I achive that? Currently, since none of the values of the dicts with `device_name.id` has an own value itself, so I cant get a next number and it just gives every device_name.id the same universe (1).

Comment: Hmm, I just noted that the signature of `get_free_universe` indicates that it doesn't take any arguments. How are you passing device_name.id as an argument in the usage above?

Comment: leftovers from some tries. Ill edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option can be to create a `set` of all the universe values in the new mapping. For example, with the mapping in the above example:

```
>>> universes = {v['universe'] for v in current.values()}
>>> universes
{1, 2}
```

Then you can use the new variable `universes` instead of `conf.values()` which you were doing above. Of course if you generate and assign a new universe, you also need to remember to add it to this hashset like so:

```
>>> universes.add(3)
>>> universes
>>> {1, 2, 3}
```

Then a slight modification is needed in the `get_free_universe` function:

```py
def get_free_universe():

    # generate a new universe
    new_universe = next(
        i
        for i in range(1, 128)
        if i not in universes
    )
    
    # add to known universes
    universes.add(new_universe)
    
    return new_universe
```

Comment: That works, with some modifications: I generate the set `universes` every time I try to setup a device, so I dont need to add in `get_free_universe()`, which gave me errors about unhashable type `dict` like the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're just looking for the first value in the range of 0 to 127 that hasn't been used as a value for any of the 'universe' keys of the dict values of your main dict:

```
def get_free_universe(conf):
    universe_values = [x['universe'] for x in conf.values()]
    return next(i for i in range(128) if i not in universe_values)
```

Note that this will throw a `StopIteration` just like your own code, if there are no free values below 128.

Comment: After the first iteration, so device one got its universe, it throws a key error for the value of the last universe. So the first universe is `1`, then it throws that key error for key `1`.
If I re-run the script, it just throws type-error: unhashable type 'dict'